# Node console.log on large array shows "... 86 more items"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm new to puppeteer. I used to have PhantomJS and CasperJS but while setting a newer server (freebsd 12) found out that support for PhantomJS is gone and CasperJS gives me segmentation faults.

I was able to port my applications to puppeteer just fine but ran into the problem that when I want to capture data from a table, this data seems to be incomplete or truncated.

I need all the info from a table but always end up getting less.

I have tried smaller tables but it also comes out truncated.
I don't know if the `console.log` buffer can be extended or not, or if there is a better way to get the values of all tds in the table.

```js
const data = await page.$$eval('table.dtaTbl tr td', tds => tds.map((td) => {
    return td.innerHTML;
}));

console.log(data);
```

I should be able to get all rows but instead I get this

```js
[ 'SF xx/xxxx 3-3999 06-01-16',
'Sample text - POLE',
  '',

 /* tons of other rows (removed by me in this example) <- */

  '',

 /* end of output */ ... 86 more items ]
```

I need the 86 other items!!!
because I'm having PHP pick it up from stdout as the code is executed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### Why `console.log` does not work

Under the hood, `console.log` uses [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), which produces output intended for debugging. To create reasonable debugging information, this function will truncate output which would be too long. To quote the docs:

> The util.inspect() method returns a string representation of object that is intended for debugging. The output of util.inspect may change at any time and **should not be depended upon programmatically**.

---

#### Solution: Use `process.stdout`

If you want to write output to `stdout` you can use [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) which is a writable stream. It will not modify/truncate what you write on the stream. You can use it like this:

```js
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(data) + '\n');
```

I added a line break at the end, as the function will not produce a line break itself (in contrast to `console.log`). If your script does not rely on it you can simply remove it.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf @JohnRalston FWIW, this `console.log()` behavior concerns direct object output, strings should not be truncated, so `console.log((JSON.stringify(data))` can suffice.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Yeah, that should work too. But I would rater write to the stream directly, instead of relying on a function that says "should not be depended upon programmatically". Or is there any advantage of using `console.log`?

Comment: @ThomasDondorf I suppose there is no advantage except simplicity.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined. why? please guide me.

Comment: @cSharma Are you in the browser environment? This question was about Node.js. You can try `console.log` instead of `process.stdout.write` in the browser.

Comment: if you want to keep the colors that `console.log()` provides while controlling how your data is truncated, you can use `process.stdout.write(util.inspect(mydata, {colors: true, depth: 5,  maxArrayLength: 20}))`

Comment: its still truncated for me in node 15 with `process.stdout.write`

Comment: I tried your solution in a React Native app, but it does not work. Do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 12):

You can also use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

instead of

```
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(data) + '\n');
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks

Comment: Note: `console.log` will unpredictably truncate the output if the object is large enough... even if you use `JSON.stringify`... that's why I'm here. The `stdout.write` method will _always_ work.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is from a couple of years ago, but this has been an issue I've seen time and time again. Discovering (through this thread) the underlying `util.inspect` call has helped me to overcome this issue in the following way:

```
process.stdout.write(`${util.inspect(data, { maxArrayLength: 1000 })}\n`)
```

By default maxArrayLength is 100 which is why the data is truncated for longer arrays.

Comment: `maxArrayLength: null` to remove any limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will achieve the same result using json objects. I was experiencing errors because the object I was trying to log was a function. As the OP experienced it was truncated, but my solution to this problem was using:

```
console.dir(object)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Do you absolutely have to use `stdout`? It's not recommended to do that for monitoring because it's very easy for `stdout` to overrun the buffer (or have incomplete output) - as you've seen illustrating the problem.

Why not modify the PHP script to read from a file as a stream using the `readfile` function, and write to that stream from your JS code using `fs`?

- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: thanks for your reply, when I started with phantomjs I used to write to file and have php parse it afterwards like you described. Later I combined both into one step. I will revert back to that, I was hoping that there was a way of printing the entire innerhtml while the script is running. thanks again