# Jest cuts off received array

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, console

I use Jest to test if a large array contains a given value:

```js
it('should contain x', () => {
  const myArray: string[] = myFunction();

  expect(myArray).toContain('x');
});
```

When the test fails, Jest cuts off the received array:

```bash
Expected value: "x"
Received array: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", ...]
```

This makes it difficult for me to check why the test failed. Can I force Jest force to print the entire received array instead of cutting it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463865/console-log-message-is-truncated) answer.

In your specific use case, I would:

```
describe("log long array", () => {
  it("logs long array", () => {
    const testArray: number[] = Array.from(Array(10000).keys()),
      expectedNumber = 99999999;

    try {
      expect(testArray).toContain(expectedNumber);
    } catch {
      console.log("Test failed! Array:", JSON.stringify(testArray));
      expect(testArray).toContain(expectedNumber);
    }
  });
});
```

You could also catch and log the error if you want

Note that I'm calling the same `expect` twice, as I still want to have the normal Jest behavior for my failing test

Alternatively, you could look into extending `jest`, allowing expect to have custom error messages with, for example, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expect-message) package, or creating a custom matcher (docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers))